# Adaline Learning Algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I can not seem to debug the following implementation of an Adaline neuron... I'm hoping someone can spot what I cannot. I think the problem lies in the last few lines of my train method?

```
from numpy import random, array, dot
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import choice
import math
import sympy

class adalineANN(object):
    def __init__(self, gamma=.2, trials=500, errors=[], weights=[]):
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.trials = trials
        self.errors = errors
        self.weights = weights

def train(self):
    self.weights = random.rand(3)

    coordinates_class1 = []
    coordinates_class2 = []

    for x in np.random.normal(2, .5, 20):
        for y in np.random.normal(3, .5, 20):
            coordinates_class1.append(([x, y, 1], 1))
            break

    for x in np.random.normal(2, .25, 20):
        for y in np.random.normal(-1, .25, 20):
            coordinates_class2.append(([x, y, 1], -1))
            break

    trainingData = coordinates_class1 + coordinates_class2

    for i in range(self.trials):
        x, target = choice(trainingData)
        y = np.dot(x, self.weights)
        error, errors = [], []
        error = (target - y)
        self.errors.append(error)
        for i in range(0, 3):
            self.weights[i] += self.gamma * x[i] * (target - y) #????* (sympy.cosh(y)**(-1))**2

def plot(self):
    plt.plot(self.errors)
    plt.show()


A = adalineANN()
A.train()
A.plot()
```

Do I need the derivative of my threshold function too? See the above note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing really wrong, but:

1. You are using "i" for iterator in **both** loops, in this code it does not matter since you do not really use it in the outer loop, but it could lead to very nasty bugs in general.
2. Your gamma is too high, change it to 0.01
3. Do not plot signed error, adaline is minimizing **squared error** thus you should plot `error = (target - y)**2`; you can even go for accuracy to see that it discriminates just fine with `error = target != np.sign(y)`.

[image: after changes]